# Insecure Use of setAtributeNS()

Tags: javascript, angular, xss

Im fixing some security issues that AppScan found on my Angular Application, one of them is the insecure use of "setAttributeNS()" I use this method in my application to inject some namespaces in the correct htmlElemnt

I have reader about the setAttribute() XSS vulnerability and that a workaround for it is directly injecting the code in the attribute name instead of using 'setAttribute()', but for setAttributeNS() I haven't found any workaround to avoid this vulnerability

Example code:

`.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", canvas.toDataURL('image/png')`

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with this. Looks like a false positive.

Comment: I also don't see why the scan keep targeting all my setAttributes()... thats why im trying a workaround for setting a namespace to the tribute, do you any workaround for this?.